# Iterate thru possible file extension to get the proper extension

Tags: php

I have a folder with many files in various formats eg .jpg, .png, .pdf, .doc etc... The files are on a remote server. I have a json file with list of filenames and its location but missing the extensions.

I want to rebuild the json file and add the proper extension to filename. How can I do this with php? Can anyone give me any ideas how to iterate thru possible extensions to get the right filename + ext on the server.

eg. I have a url like this - http://www.somesite.com/filename. I know on the server the file is pdf but how can I do this programatically for many files which may be different  and rename the url?

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a good place to start https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures, and this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_signature

Comment: You might want to fire some HEAD requests at your remote server for different filename/extension permutations.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [For Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) To loop over [all current know file extensions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and execute a GET request to the `$url . $extension` and see if the server returns a file.

If the server returns a file, you can break the for loop.

You can nest 2 for loops in each other to do this far all know urls.

**Example**

```
$files = [
    "http://test.com/test",
    "http://test.com/test2"
];


$extensions = [
    ".jpg",
    ".docx"
];

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    foreach ($extensions as $extension)
    {
        $foundFile = // Get requests here
        if(FILE_IS_FOUND){
            // Store file where ever you need it

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses a [Foreach Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)